# How to detect if browser supports focus on disabled elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, focus, feature-detection

> Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus

jQuery threw the above error on IE8.

I'd like to be able to detect if the browser supports focus on disabled elements (an `input` in my case), and store it in `jQuery.support`.

How would I do this?

A plain JS solution would be fine, but I don't want to use browser sniffing (`jQuery.browser`, etc).

Would using `dispatchEvent()` be a good way to go?

Comment: you mean disabled `<input>` elements?

Comment: any reason you don't want to check if control is visible and enabled before setting focus to it?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt In other browsers this works fine. There's third party stuff triggered on focus, so I don't want to check if it's visible. That would block that use in other browsers unless I did browser sniffing. Also, I would just prefer to do a check and store the result in `jQuery.support` when the page loads.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? i can't seem to get it to throw said error in 1.8.2 on a disabled element.

Comment: @KevinB I'm using 1.7.2. I'll try 1.8.2

Comment: @KevinB The element needs to be in the DOM before you focus it. Adam, the problem occurs in 1.8.2 as well (just tested in jsfiddle)

Comment: @Asad thanks for that. I was having frustrating problems clearing my cache anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could just `try`, `catch` exactly that (focusing a disabled element), and store a value in `support` if anything borks.

```
var test = $('<input disabled/>');
$(document.body).append(test);
try{
    test.focus();
}catch(e){
    //no support, do your thing
    //...
}
//clean up test element
test.remove();
```

Comment: lol.. I couldnt think of anything else myself but was afraid to post as a solution in fear of the wrath of the SO critics.. lol..good on ya..+1

Comment: Why not go to a lower level? Could I try using `dispatchEvent()`?

Comment: @AdamLynch Why go to a lower level? You could certainly try, but I don't see the point, seeing as somewhere in the code for `focus()` this is already happening.

Comment: Maybe it would be faster (I'm not sure if that's true). Like how using `$('#id').find('.class')` is faster than using `$('#id .class')` because jQuery eventually decides it should use the former when given the latter after some time.

Comment: @AdamLynch This is a one time check, not an iteration. It can at most improve your performance by a millisecond or two.

Comment: Ugh. Got this really weird bug now. The `catch` above breaks a placeholder polyfill (I'm using [this one](https://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder) I think) in IE8 (the placeholder is not hidden on click/focus of field, with no errors). What's strange is that it works if I comment out the above catch. It breaks even if the exception is renamed or the catch is even empty. Any ideas? Can't find anything related online

Comment: @AdamLynch I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: @AdamLynch Could you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Asad, here you go: working [without try-catch](https://raw.github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder/master/html5placeholder.jquery.min.js), not working [with the try-catch](http://jsfiddle.net/57wgy/6/)

Comment: It seems like it's the `focus` call that is causing problems outside of the try-catch, the try-catch [doesn't seem to be a problem on it's own](http://jsfiddle.net/57wgy/7/)

Comment: Ok, [got it](http://jsfiddle.net/57wgy/8/). This seems like unexpected behaviour to me, gonna add an issue to the jQuery GitHub.